# If Hamiltonian is invariant under a group $G$, then for $R\in G$ , $R\Psi$ has the same energy. Arfken

Tags: schroedinger-equation, group-theory

I've never taken quantum mechanics (only a class on modern physics) but I'm reading Arfken's section on Group theory. I don't understand what is trying to be proved here. It seems like a tautology to me:

[image]

Why does it seem like a tautology to me? Well, if $H\Psi=E\Psi$ then it should be obvious that $H(R\Psi)=E(R\Psi)$. I think my confusion is related to the fact that I don't know how $E$ as $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is energy.

But I'm not looking for a physics answer to be honest. I don't want any physical argument or something. I just don't know what is being proven mathematically here.

My question really boils down to: Why does the expression imply "$R\Psi$" has the same energy?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm as confused as you by the boxed equation. At best the author is making that all-too-common mistake of reordering the expressions in a transitive equals relation, making the equation nonsensical when read left to right.

However, it is not quite a tautology to prove what I think this is trying to prove:

> If $E$ and $\psi$ satisfy $H \psi = E \psi$, then $H (R \psi) = E (R \psi)$ whenever $H$ is invariant under conjugation by $R$.

The proof is better written as
$$ H (R \psi) = R (H \psi) = R (E \psi) = E (R \psi), $$
where we use invariance, the eigenvalue equation for $\psi$, and the commutivity of operators with scalars, respectively. Without invariance, the first equality of mine wouldn't necessarily hold. That is, rotating a state could change its energy:
$$ H (R \psi) = E' (R \psi) \neq E (R \psi). $$
Remember, each energy eigenstate $\psi$ can have its own distinct eigenvalue $E$.

Comment: E doesn't have the meaning $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ here right? Namely, its a scalar right?

Comment: Oh I think I've just found out that E is never $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$